# How to mock scala generic method

Tags: scala, mockito

I have a traits(below simple versions) and I want to mock `Foo`.

```
trait MyTrait[A]

trait Foo {
  def bar[T: MyTrait](id:Int, data: T, other:Option[String] = None): String
}
```

I tried:

```
implicit val myTrait = new MyTrait[String] {}

val src = mock[Foo]
when(src.bar(any(),any(),any())).thenReturn("ok")

src.bar(1, "some", None)
```

It fails with:

> Invalid use of argument matchers! 4 matchers expected, 3 recorded

How to mock this kind of method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax `[T : MyTrait]` is sugar to add `(implicit typeClass: MyTrait[T])` as a second set of arguments, so basically you're missing an argument matcher as the error states

So if you do

```
val src = mock[Foo]
when(src.bar(any(),any(),any())(any())).thenReturn("ok")
```

it works as expected

BTW, this is a bit of self promotion but I just published a library called `mockito-scala` that improves the mockito syntax for Scala, is part of the mockito ecosystem so hopefully should become the default when working with Scala, you can find it here https://github.com/mockito/mockito-scala with the information to get the dependency and what problems does it actually solves.

Answer (score 2):

Mockito does not play well with scala code. What happens in your case is that 
`notify.bar(any(), any(), any())` has to be invoked inside `when()`, but type of the bar method is unknown, so when scalac is looking-up implicits there are possibly several instances of `Writes` that fit here (becuase all of them do).
You can do something like this to make it work:

```
when(src.bar[T](any(),any(),any())).thenReturn("ok")
```

**Edit**

Following your edit, i think you should reconsider usage of mockito in the first place. Here's what happens:
Foo has the following signature after desugaring

```
trait Foo {
 def bar[T](id:Int, data: T, other:Option[String] = None)(implicit ev: MyTrait[T]): String
}
```

I don't know if you are aware how does mockito work, but here is a quick explanation why (from what i can tell) this error happens:

- at runtime method bar has the following "signature" (due to type erasure):
  `bar(id: Int, data: Object, other: Option[Object], ev: MyTrait[Object])`
- `when(src.bar[T](any(),any(),any())).thenReturn("ok")` actually invokes this method on a proxy object and registers "matchers", but ev is passed `myTrait` instead of a matcher, so i guess this violates some constraints of the library

As side-note: usually mocking is not that hard and you can simply implement a "mocked" trait without any help from mockito or other similar library.

Comment: Code requires concrete type, not `T`. Still dont know how make it work

Comment: I did not know the specific type you were using, so leaved `T`, replace it with anything you need.